# Perl and gethostbyname weird behavior

Tags: perl, hostname, gethostbyname

I'm running the following:

```
perl -wl -e 'print gethostbyname ("1234");'
123424Ò
```

also running `gethostbyname ("1")` returns a defined result, this does not meet with what is written [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_gethostbyname.htm) at all.

I'm wondering if I should even use this method? what im trying to do is to find if a given hostname is valid.

Comment: These return the expected result (undefined) for me. All this does is contact the system's name-resolving service, so perhaps you have something funny going on there? (Tested Perl 5.16.1 on Win32)

Answer (score 1):

Type `1249767172` into your browser, and you might end up visiting Google. That's because a valid IP address is merely a number between 0 and 4294967295.

Sure, you're more familiar with the dotted form notation (`74.125.239.4`), but many places also accept the decimal number directly (`1249767172`) or even a hex notation (`0x4A7DEF04`).

Since you're providing valid IP addresses, no errors are being returned.

```
$ perl -MSocket=inet_ntoa -E'
    my $addr = gethostbyname($ARGV[0]);
    say inet_ntoa($addr);
' 1249767172
74.125.239.4

$ perl -MSocket=inet_ntoa -E'
    my $addr = gethostbyname($ARGV[0]);
    say inet_ntoa($addr);
' 1
0.0.0.1

$ perl -MSocket=inet_ntoa -E'
    my $addr = gethostbyname($ARGV[0]);
    say inet_ntoa($addr);
' 1234
0.0.4.210
```

(Exact behaviour may vary by system. The `gethostbyname` from my Windows and my cygwin builds don't recognize those numbers, although FireFox on the same machine does.)